# How do I find $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$ if $2x+3y=5$ is the tangent of $f(x)$ at $x=1$?

Tags: derivatives

> Find $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$ if $2x+3y=5$ is the tangent of $f(x)$ at $x=1$.

Is this correct:
$$2x+3y=5$$
$$3y=5-2x$$
$$y=5/3-(2/3)x$$
From here I get that $f'(1) = -2/3$. Here I am not sure how to continue for $f(1)$? If I just replace it in $y=5/3-2/3x$, I get $y=5/3-2/3=3/3=1$, but I am not sure if this is correct?

Comment: Yes, your calculation is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct:

If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, the tangent line of $f$ at $x_0$ is by definition the line $y = f'(x_0) (x-x_0) + f(x_0) $. So if the line $y = \alpha x + \beta$ is the tangent line of $f$ at $x = x_0$ then

$$
f'(x_0) = \alpha
$$

and

$$
f(x_0) = \alpha x_0 + \beta.
$$